# Are object oriented languages more powerful than declarative programming languages

Tags: oop, declarative-programming

Are object oriented languages more powerful than declarative programming languages? By powerful I mean are they able to solve a class of problems that any program written in a declarative programming language can't?

Personally I don't think so. There exists a set of problems for which it is easier to write a program using an object-oriented language, but I think those problems could be solved using declarative languages too (albeit it might be harder to so)

Would like to hear more views on this one.

Comment: No. That would go against turing complete-ness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go read up on [Turing completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). It basically means any turing complete language can solve any problem a turing machine can.

And most languages are turing complete. (I doubt you'd ever use a non turing complete language).

Alternatively you can think of it as you can solve any problem with [Ook!](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/ook.html) even though it's a very silly language.

Comment: Nitpick: True Turing completeness is unattainable by any language that's running on a real machine.  Turing equivalence is about the best one can achieve.

Comment: @cHao whats the difference? Is it the infinite tape restriction?

Comment: Turing completeness, by definition, is the ability to simulate a Turing machine.  And a Turing machine has infinite tape (memory).  No real-world machine (and thus, no language designed to make programs to run on said machine) can satisfy that criterion.